# Given $n$ real intervals, prove there exists either $\sqrt{n}$ disjoint intervals, either $\sqrt{n}$ intervals having a common point

Tags: combinatorics

I'm supposed to use Dilworth's theorem but I don't see how.

I gave a look at the corrected version of the exercise and they define, if we denote $P = \{I_1, I_2, ..., I_n \}$, $I_i = (a_i, b_i) \subset \Bbb R$, the set of our $n$ intervals, a partial order on $P$ such that $I_i \leq I_j \iff I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset$ and $\sup\{x \in I_i \} = b_i \leq a_j = \inf\{x \in I_j\}$, but I don't see how this binary relation is reflexive.

Comment: This relation is not reflexive, actually it is antireflexive. It's a strict partial order.

Comment: @Crostul But then, we cannot use Dilworth's theorem (or could we ?). So, what they did would be wrong ?

Comment: Should it be $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ rather than just $\sqrt n$ ?

Comment: @Desura A strict partial order is an antireflexive, antisymmetric, transitive relation. So, if $<'$ is a strict partial order, you can consider the partial order $\le'$ defined by $x \le' y$ if and only if $(x<'y$ or $x=y)$.

Comment: @learner: It should be interpreted as ‘at least $\sqrt{n}$’ in both places.

Comment: @Crostul Oh, thank you. I didn't know about the link between both.